# Simulate the mean of a First Passage Time of a Wiener Process

Tags: r, simulation

Let $\{B(t)\}$ be a Brownian motion, $\{X(t)\}$ be a Brownian motion with drift $X(t) = B(t) + t$ and
$\tau(x) := \inf\{t > 0 : X(t) = x\}$.

Find $\mathbb{E}[\tau(1)]$ by simulation using :

1. discrete interpolation
2. linear interpolation for a sufficient fine grid.

What I thought of so far for 1.

```
#Set b_0 = 0 and b_1 = rnorm(1)
b_t <- c()
b_t[1] <- 0
b_t[2] <- rnorm(1)
x=1
#Find the first passage time so when does X(t) hit 1 for the first time
while(b_t[x]<1){
b_t[x+2] <- rnorm(n = 1, mean = (b_t[x+1]- b_t[x] )/2, sd =  x/2)  
x <- x+1
}
```

I believe my code fails to generate the bivariate sectioning correctly. Can someone help ?

Comment: Hello on CV! Instead of asking for help in general, specify your question - why do you believe your code fails? What is the expected output and what is the actual output?

Comment: Hi: First you should work on simulating a brownian motion $B(t$) by generating some discrete process with a fine enough grid. ( Stefan Iacus's useR sde book will show how to do that ) Then, once you have that correct, the other issues are more programming-detail oriented and you can ask about those if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with. Haven't done this particular simulation before though so there could be errors - beware:

```
# Total time to run simulation
TT <- 100
# Drift term
mu <- 0.01
# Variance term
sigma <- 2
# Time step
delta_t <- 0.05
# Level to be crossed
x <- 30 

# Time vector
T <- seq(0, TT, delta_t) 

# Unit normals
Z <- rnorm(length(T), 0, 1)

# Brownian motion variates
X <- cumsum(sigma* sqrt(T)*Z + mu*T)

# Plot and print results
plot(T, X, type="l", main="Brownian Motion")
if(x > 0 && max(X) > x) {
    tau <- T[min(which(X > x))]
    cat("Time at which BM crossed ", x, ": ", tau, sep="")
} else if(x <= 0 && min(X) < x) {
    tau <- T[min(which(X < x))]
    cat("Time at which BM crossed ", x, ": ", tau, sep="")
} else {
    cat("BM didn't cross ", x, sep="")
}
```